# getting extra bytes 82 00 in pc/sc response

Tags: nfc, smartcard, sony, contactless-smartcard, pcsc

I am trying to read data from sony felica card using pc/sc transparent session and transceive data object.

The response I am getting is for a read without encryption command is

**c0 03  00 90 00 92 01  00 96 02 00 00 97 82 00 + Data**

But according to the protocol, the response should be

**c0 03  00 90 00 92 01  00 96 02 00 00 97 + Data**

I am unable to figure out the last 82 00 appended in the response from the card.

Now when I try to authenticate with the card I get

**c0 03 01 6F 01 90 00**

which is a error in pc/sc. I want to resolve these extra bytes 82 00 which I believe will solve the issue with all the commands which require authentication and encryption.

Answer (score 1):

The response data is [BER-TLV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#BER_encoding) encoded (see [PC/SC 2.02, Part 3](http://pcscworkgroup.com/Download/Specifications/pcsc3_v2.02.00_sup2.pdf)).

In BER-TLV encoding there are several possibilities to encode tag `0x97` with two octets of data `0xD0D1`, e.g.:

- `97|02|D0D1` -- short form ([see parsed](https://www.emvlab.org/tlvutils/?data=9702D0D1))
- `97|8102|D0D1` -- long form with one octet with length ([see parsed](https://www.emvlab.org/tlvutils/?data=978102D0D1))
- `97|820002|D0D1` -- long form with two octets with length ([see parsed](https://www.emvlab.org/tlvutils/?data=97820002D0D1))
- `97|83000002|D0D1` -- long form with three octets with length ([see parsed](https://www.emvlab.org/tlvutils/?data=9783000002D0D1))
- ...

Your reader is using two octets for sending the length of *ICC Response* data object (which is perfectly valid).

You should parse the response properly...Good luck!

PS: The above means, that the `Data` part of your truncated responses still contains one extra byte with the response length (i.e. `Len|Data`)

Comment: yes, you are right but then why only the mutual auth command is failing for felica?

Comment: Could you update your question with a complete APDU trace? And which reader are you using (as 6F01 is not defined by PC/SC -- the nearest one is `XX 6F 00` -- *Data object XX failed, no precise diagnosis*)?